# General formula needed for this product rule expression (differential operator)

Tags: calculus, sobolev-spaces

Let $D_i^t$, $D_i^0$ for $i=1,\dots,n$ be differential operators. (For example $D_1^t = D_x^t$, $D_2^t = D_y^t,\dots$, where $x$, $y$ are the coordinates).

Suppose I am given the identity
$${D}_a^t (F_t u) = \sum_{j=1}^n F_t({D}_j^0 u){D}_a^t\varphi_j$$
where $\varphi_j$ are smooth functions and $F_t$ is some nice map. So
$$
D^t_bD^t_a(F_t u) = \sum_j D^t_b\left(F_t({D}_j^0 u)\right){D}_a^t\varphi_j+\sum_j F_t({D}_j^0 u)D^t_b{D}_a^t\varphi_j
$$
and because
$${D}_b^t (F_t (D_j^0u)) = \sum_{k=1}^n F_t({D}_k^0 D_j^0u){D}_b^t\varphi_k,$$ we have
$$D^t_bD^t_a(F_t u) =  \sum_{j,k=1}^n F_t({D}_k^0 D_j^0u){D}_b^t\varphi_k+\sum_j F_t({D}_j^0 u)D^t_b{D}_a^t\varphi_j
.$$
My question is how do I generalise this and obtain a rule for
$$D^t_{\alpha} (F_t u)$$ where
$\alpha$ is a multiindex of order $n$ (or order $m$)? My intention is to put the derivatives on $u$ and put the $F_t$ outside, like I demonstrated above.

Can anyone help me with getting the formula for this? It's really tedious to write out multiple derivatives so it's hard to tell for me.

Answer (score 3):

This is probably better served as a comment, but I can't add one because of lack of reputation. If I understand correctly you are probably looking for the multivariate version of [Faà di Bruno's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno%27s_formula#Multivariate_version), beware that the Wikipedia entry uses slightly different notation.